# White screen after saving changes with NativeScript Angular HMR on Android emulator

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I created a NativeScript 7.1 project with Angular 11 using `tns create my-blank-ng --template @nativescript/template-blank-ng` and then run it using `tns run`.

The app at first runs perfectly, but it only shows a white screen after saving changes which triggers hot reload.

Is there any way to make HMR work? Disabling HMR could be a workaround, but it's to annoying to have the app restart on each change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug - fixed in nativescript-angular@11.0.1

Release note:
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/releases/tag/11.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, but it seems like although [they announced that it now works](https://nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-7-1-hmr-reenabled-and-xcode-12-3-support/), with Angular it still **does not**.

I don't think there's any workarounds at this time. We'll have to wait...

**Update:** There's also an issue on this at: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/2243

**Update 2:** Fixed, see accepted answer.